# Convolution of an integrable function with $|x|^{-\alpha}$ is finite a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, convolution, harmonic-analysis

> Let $\alpha\in(0,1)$ and $g(x)=|x|^{-\alpha}$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Prove that if $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ is non-negative and 
>   $$K(x)=f*g(x)=\int_\mathbb{R}f(x-y)g(y)dy=\int_\mathbb{R}f(y)g(x-y)dy,$$
>   then $K$ is finite a.e. on $\mathbb{R}$.

I notice that $K\notin L^{p}$ for any $p\geq1$. So it seems that Holder inequality doesn't work. Moreover, it suffices to show that $\int_\mathbb{R}K(x)dx<\infty$. But how do we prove that?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1042479/hardy-littlewood-sobolev-inequality-without-marcinkiewicz-interpolation)

Comment: Write $g = g\cdot \chi_{(-1,1)} + g\cdot \chi_{\mathbb{R}\setminus (-1,1)}$.

Comment: I got it. Thanks.