# An inequality for Sobolev functions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Let $\Omega$ be a smooth bounded domain and $f\in L^p(\Omega)$, $u\in W^{1,1}(\Omega)$ such that $p\geq 1$. Then
$$
\int_{\Omega}|fu|\,dx\leq C\,\int_{\omega}\{|f(x)|dx(\int_{\Omega}\frac{|\nabla u(\zeta)|}{|x-\zeta|^{n-1}}\,d\zeta+||f||_{L^1(\Omega)})\}\leq\,C\{(\int_{\Omega}\int_{\Omega}\frac{|f(x)|}{|x-\zeta|^{n-\frac{1}{q}}}d\zeta\,dx)^{1-\frac{1}{n}} (\int_{\Omega}|\nabla\zeta|^n\,d\zeta\int_{\Omega}\frac{|f(x)|\,dx}{|x-\zeta|^\frac{n-1}{q}})^\frac{1}{n}+||u||_{L^1(\Omega)}||f||_{L^1(\Omega)}         \}
$$
for some positive constant $C$.
In the above line, I have used the following Lemma 1, proved in Trudinger 1967 paper which states that for any $u\in W^{1,1}(\Omega)$, we have
$$
|u(x)|\leq C(n)\{\int_{\Omega}\frac{|\nabla u(\zeta)|}{|x-\zeta|^{n-1}}\,d\zeta+||u||_{L^1(\Omega)}\}.
$$

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: What is the exact question? You don't understand how to use the Lemma to obtain your inequality or you need a proof of the Lemma? It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: I am very sorry to bother you about the exact question. The exact question is how to get the first inequality using the Lemma stated at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you use the Lemma to get 
\begin{align}\int_{\Omega}|fu|\,dx&\leq C\,\int_{\Omega}|f(x)|\left(\int_{\Omega}\frac{|\nabla u(\zeta)|}{|x-\zeta|^{n-1}}\,d\zeta+||u||_{L^1(\Omega)}\right)dx
\\&=\int_{\Omega}\int_{\Omega}|f(x)|\frac{|\nabla u(\zeta)|}{|x-\zeta|^{n-1}}\,d\zeta dx+\int_{\Omega}|f(x)|\,dx||u||_{L^1(\Omega)}\end{align}
Since $$\frac{n-1}n\left(n-\frac1q\right)+\frac1n\frac{n-1}{q}=n-1$$ you can rewrite the first term on the right-hand side as
$$\int_{\Omega}\int_{\Omega}\left(\frac{|f(x)|}{|x-\zeta|^{n-1/q}}\right)^{(n-1)/n}\left(\frac{|f(x)|}{|x-\zeta|^{(n-1)/q}}\right)^{1/n}|\nabla u(\zeta)|\,d\zeta dx $$ and use Holder's inequality with exponent $p=n$ and $p'=\frac{n}{n-1}$
to bound this term from above by
$$\left(\int_{\Omega}\int_{\Omega}\frac{|f(x)|}{|x-\zeta|^{n-1/q}}\,d\zeta dx\right)^{(n-1)/n}\left(\int_{\Omega}\int_{\Omega}\frac{|f(x)|}{|x-\zeta|^{(n-1)/q}}|\nabla u(\zeta)|^n\,d\zeta dx\right)^{1/n}. $$
In the last term you can use Fubini's term to separate the integrals.

Comment: Thank you very much for the nice steps, but in the last time there is one $q$ such that $q=\frac{p}{p-1}$

Comment: OK but then there is something wrong in what you wrote. You should have $|f(x)|^p$ somewhere. Can you check if you what you wrote is correct? The only other tool you can use is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1042479/hardy-littlewood-sobolev-inequality-without-marcinkiewicz-interpolation

Comment: I have attached the link from where pdf file can be accessed. May I kindly request you t have a look at the first step of the proof of Theorem 2. https://sci-hub.tw/10.1512/iumj.1968.17.17028

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look tonight after work

Comment: Thank You very much. I am waiting to hear from you.

Comment: I just updated it

Comment: Thank you very very much for such a nice solution.

Comment: Welcome. If you think it is correct, then you should accept it. Theses are the instructions. "To accept an answer:
Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.
To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.
You may change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the answer, at any time."